# Meaning of "wie" in "Minutenlang wurde wie wild an der Tür geklopft und gerüttelt."

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What is the meaning of *wie* in the following sentence? And what is this usage/construction called?

> Minutenlang wurde wie wild an der Tür geklopft und gerüttelt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning here is "like". Compare English "like crazy".

In this usage, "wie" is considered a *Vergleichspartikel* (comparison particle).

The combination of "wie" with an adjective is not unusual in German. A similar expression is "wie verrückt" which has the same meaning as the aforementioned English "like crazy".

Comment: Although "wie wild" is a commonly used phrase, the "wie" can be omitted here: *Minutenlang wurde wild an der Tür geklopft und gerüttelt.*