# "wie angewurzelt stehen bleiben"-breaking down into sentence members

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

Here is a sentence:

> Er blieb wie angewurzelt stehen.

I get the overall meaning of the phrase. However, for the sake of having a better command over its usage, I would like to know what sentence member "wie angewurzelt" is. Is it an adverbial of manner or an ellipsis of a Nebensatz?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/67806/meaning-of-wie-in-minutenlang-wurde-wie-wild-an-der-t%c3%bcr-geklopft-und-ger%c3%bcttel

Comment: Routinely querying a decent dictionary might also help, see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anwurzeln). If it does not, it will at least assist in better targeting the question.

Comment: @guidot - DWDS happens to have a separate entry for "wie angewurzelt".

Answer (score 2):

It's an implicit comparison in place of a modal adverbial. You could simplify it as

> Er bliebt angewurzelt stehen.

but that would mean that he grew roots for real and not just metaphorically. That item *angewurzelt* is a Partizip II and participles work like adjectives so they can modify verbs directly as in this example.

But you may also use *wie angewurzelt* as a floating modal adverbial as in the following example:

> Er blieb in dem Moment wie angewurzelt an seinem Platz stehen.